# Is there a O(n) algorithm to build a min-heap?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

If the input array is sorted lets say for example the numbers from 1 to n
in increasing order then will it take O(n) to build a minimum heap from an array like this ?

Edit 1 :- I know that if we build a minimum heap from n elements then it will have a Ω(n*log n) run time in worst case but is the sorted order of these n elements in an increasing order a way to build a minimum heap in O(n) worst case run time ?

Edit 2 :- Is it possible that we can build a minimum heap from an n sized array in a decreasing order in O(n) ? and if so then why ?

Comment: If the array is sorted, it is already in heap order. So, assuming you are modeling your heap as an array, you don't need to do anything at all, which is significantly better than O(n). Unless perhaps you need to copy the array to the heap…

Comment: yes I need to copy the array to the heap and not just represent the heap as an array

Comment: Your array **is** already a heap

Comment: Do you read answers? Both contain links to complexity description.

Answer (score 0):

If array is sorted - it already **is** min-heap because main heap property `A[i]<= A[2*i]` and `A[i]<= A[2*i+1]` *(for 1-based numeration)* is true.

Note that heap building process takes O(n) time for any source array. [Arbitrary found source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-of-building-a-heap/)

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia on Binary Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap):

> Heaps are commonly implemented with an array. Any binary tree can be
>   stored in an array, but because a binary heap is always a complete
>   binary tree, it can be stored compactly.

All details given on the page.